# disable swap partitions completely

Tags: partitioning, swap

How to disable all swap partitions completely.
I have applied the following tasks on the server.

1. sudo swapoff -a
2. deleted line (/swap.img      none    swap    sw      0       0) from /etc/fstab.

I still can see.

```
Server2-2@server2-2:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                               13G  2.7M   13G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   15G   79G  16% /
tmpfs                               63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                           13T  227M   12T   1% /hdd/storage1
/dev/sde1                           13T   28K   12T   1% /hdd/storage4
/dev/sdd1                           13T   28K   12T   1% /hdd/storage3
/dev/sdc1                           13T   28K   12T   1% /hdd/storage2
tmpfs                               13G  4.0K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
Server2-2@server2-2:~$
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: You still can see what? I don't see any swap there, what is the problem?

Comment: You turned off all swapping, then removed a swap file (not a partition). Then you show us a list of all partitions (swap or otherwise) mounted on your system. You can't draw any conclusions from that list. Do `cat /proc/swaps` to see all active swaps.

Comment: May I ask why you want to disable swap? Also, are you trying to disable swappiness or are you trying to simply only use a swapfile instead of a swap partition?

Comment: swap partiotion is turned off with the following command "sudo swapoff -a" and swap file also deleted. then verfied with "free -mtl | grep -i swap"